# APNS and message queue

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, message-queue, apple-push-notifications

How can I set up a queue on a Java side Server to invoke the APNS only every 5 min. So that I do not overload my user with constant mail Push Notifications, but rather update the App only every 5 min. with a total badge number of email messages from the server (Hope this makes sense). So Apple has nothing in place to create such an event, rather the message are pushed as they arrive from server.

Does Java have a mail queue type Class and Methods that can be timer based per say organization (not server or url or user) and then invoke the APNS with total number ?

Thanks in advnace

Answer (score 0):

There's lots of Java job schedulers.  [This comparison](http://java.dzone.com/articles/feature-comparison-java-job) will get you started.